# Something strange while adding items to listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

When i'm getting new list, i'm setting it as

```
Items = new List<SingleItem>(listOfItems)
```

and that works fine.

But when i'm adding to the list via

```
foreach (var item in listOfItemsSecondPart)
        {
            Items.Add(item);
        }
```

I'm getting some weird things. Debugger shows, that all items are added succeafully. Scrollbox decreases its scale, like when list was grown. But the problem is that list is still pretty the same. It cant be rolled down, so scrollbox stops somewhere in the middle.

Anybody faced that? Probably that starts after last Windows 8 update (device is Lumia 920), but i'm not pretty sure.

Edit: ok, i made some investigation: if the list is empty, and i'm adding items with "foreach", it is still empty. Looking like notification is not rising, because debugger shows that list is filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead.

The UI have no chance of knowing that the `List<T>` has been updated, but the `ObservableCollection<T>` will emit events when modified that the UI can pick up.

Comment: Yep, just figured out 3 minutes ago, that it was caused by moving from ObservableCollection to List. I am using Mvvm light, so i have setter, but it is not risen after Add(), only after constructor.

Comment: Hm.. cant i just force notification just by calling **Set(() => Items, ref _items, _items);** right after foreach?